# update database java

Tags: java, sql, updates

I'm working on database containing 2 columns (NOM (String) ,TMP(integer)).
But when I tried to update it , the first row became the last.
Can I update it and maintain the same order?

```
  Statement state = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

      ResultSet result = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cities");

      result.absolute(1);
      result.updateString("NOM", "xxx");
      result.updateRow();
```

[image]
Here's my databasebefore and after the excution of my code.

Comment: Not related to your question, but having a city name as a primary key could cause problems because they are not necessarily unique.

Comment: You're operating under a misconception: tables in SQL have no inherent order.  That it returned rows in order of the primary key was at the discretion of the db.  Without an `ORDER BY ...` statement, the db will return rows in whatever order it pleases.  You do not have (any?) control over this, it is influenced by factors outside of your direct control (ie, current disk read usage).  If you want a specific row, use a `WHERE` clause.  If you want the first row, you need `ORDER BY`, or you'll (eventually) get different results when you least expect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results are displayed ordered by primary key.  Since you changed the primary key `nom` field the ordering changed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Brent is correct. Normally the results are sorted by primary key in the tables. As you changed the primary key so it is showing the updated order.